# Play services 5.2.08 Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
```

is always returning 2 as response although my play services is already updated.

IDE: Android studio 0.8.9

Device: Nexus 5 (4.4.4)

BuildToolsVersion: 20.0.0

but if i use older Play services everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Device with android 4.4.4 has play service version 5.0.89 where as devices with android L preview has play service version 5.2.08. This is reason why android studio ask you to update your play service version to 5.2.08. So, for now use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

And if you want to update your play service to 5.2 see [this](https://plus.google.com/+DerekRoss/posts/G2LJ7vDRbc7).

if you are using android L emulator, i think you are free to use 5.2.08 see [configure project for developer preview](https://developers.google.com/fit/preview#configure_your_project)